# Disabled button with DOM but cant enable it and get it back to visible again

Tags: css, dom, xhtml

I have a button in html called btnS:

```
<button type="submit" id="btnS" class="hide" value="button">Send</button>
```

That I disabled with dom via external script dom:

```
btnS.setAttribute('disabled', 'false');
```

I tried to get it "back on" again via:

```
btnS.setAttribute('enabled', 'true');
```

But that didn't work? The button was first invisible via a css rule:

```
.hide {
    visibility : hidden;
}
```

And I changed that as well before with :

```
btnS.setAttribute('class', 'show');
```

Rule:

```
.show {     visibility:visible; }
```

Comment: I'd advise against using `true` & `false` as attribute values for boolean attributes. In fact, I'd advise against touching either of those attributes from JavaScript. Hint: use properties.

Comment: Ok good I'll keep that in mind, tx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one attribute:

```
var btnS = document.getElementById("btnS");

// Disable
btnS.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');

// Enable
btnS.removeAttribute('disabled');
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `disabled="false"` actually means "disable this element": any `disabled` attribute (even an empty one) means "disabled the element".

You need to remove the attribute:

```
btnS.removeAttribute('hidden');
```

<s>Alternatively</s> For better results, work with the DOM property:

```
btnS.disabled = true;
btnS.disabled = false;
```

Comment: The DOM property method is the way to go. The attribute methods are fishy in some versions of IE. Plus, properties for boolean attributes actually act like booleans.

Comment: @MattMcDonald Absolutely: I've reworded my answer to reflect this.